# Statistical analysis for comparing expertise levels between 3 groups

Tags: group-differences, case-control-study

I hope you are all safe and healthy considering the current climate.

I was wondering if someone could help with a statistical dilemma I have on my hands.

I am trying to explore whether IQ tests can distinguish academics of difference expertise levels.

I have an overall of 63 participants. 17 professors, 26 PhD students and 19 bachelor students. These have then been split into 7 nominal categories of experience levels (i.e. bachelor 1-3 year, etc).I have tested them on 4 individual IQ tests. My data is not normally distributed, as to be expected. I want to perform the test on SPSS.

What statistical analysis can I now run, to determine whether certain individuals of specific experience levels have higher IQ tests. That is, do people with more experience score higher on IQ tests.

Comment: You can still do ANOVA with non-normal data. Searching Cross Validated for "anova with non-normal data" brings up quite a number of results.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I have already run non-parametric tests because I have a smaller sample size and unequal small sub-groups. Do you think running a Kruskal Wallis test with Dunn post hoc may also suffice?